# postgresql error - ERROR: input is out of range

Tags: postgresql, function

The function below keeps returning this error message.  I thought that maybe the double_precision field type was what was causing this, and I tried to use CAST, but either that's not it, or I didn't do it right...  Help?

Here's the error:

```
ERROR:  input is out of range
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "calculate_distance" line 7 at RETURN

********** Error **********

ERROR: input is out of range
SQL state: 22003
Context: PL/pgSQL function "calculate_distance" line 7 at RETURN
```

And here's the function:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_distance(character varying, 
double precision, double precision, 
double precision, double precision)

      RETURNS double precision AS
    $BODY$ 
            DECLARE earth_radius double precision; 

            BEGIN 
                    earth_radius := 3959.0; 

                    RETURN earth_radius * acos(sin($2 / 57.2958) * 
sin($4 / 57.2958) + cos($2/ 57.2958) * cos($4 / 57.2958) 
* cos(($5 / 57.2958) - ($3 / 57.2958)));
            END; 
            $BODY$
      LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
      COST 100;
    ALTER FUNCTION calculate_distance(character varying, 
double precision, double precision, double precision, 
double precision) OWNER TO postgres;



    //I tried changing (unsuccessfully) that RETURN line to: 

    RETURN CAST( (earth_radius * acos(sin($2 / 57.2958) 
* sin($4 / 57.2958) + cos($2/ 57.2958) * cos($4 / 57.2958) 
* cos(($5 / 57.2958) - ($3 / 57.2958))) ) AS text);
```

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at this solution:

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/12376732.post@talk.nabble.com

> The problem was indeed ACOS() being outside of the [-1,1] range, and
>   this happened because it was calculating the distance between the same
>   LAT,LONG pair (the same location)
>
> I added a WHERE L1.ID <> L2.ID to stop the reflexive calculation.
>
> Martijn van Oosterhout wrote:
>
> > On Sat, Aug 18, 2007 at 03:21:02PM -0700, dustov wrote:
> >
> > > My database just had this new error, and I have no idea why (because I
> > >       haven't intentionally made any changes to this table).   Does anyone have
> > >       an
> > >       idea which input is out of range-- or what the problem might be?
> >
> > The only thing in your query that I can imagine being out of range is
> >     ACOS() which would need to be between -1 and 1 (otherwise the result
> >     would be complex).
> >
> > I'd try and see what the argument to the ACOS is, but it's probably
> >     some corner case where the rounding is getting you.
> >
> > Hope this helps,

I had the same error with calculating the distance between coordinates but the above tip solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

Little late but had the same problem and it happens because acos param is outside [-1,1] (maybe 1.01)
before calculating ACOS you should cast as INTEGER that value

like this:

```
        RETURN  (earth_radius * acos(CAST ((sin($2 / 57.2958) 
sin($4 / 57.2958) + cos($2/ 57.2958) * cos($4 / 57.2958) 
 cos(($5 / 57.2958) - ($3 / 57.2958)) AS INTEGER)) );
```

Comment: That can't be right, you'd end up making everything `0` or `1`

Answer (score 4):

It's due to a floating point rounding error taking the value to >1.

Before taking the ACOS limit the value to the range -1 to 1 with [least and greatest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST)

```
acos(least(greatest(...),-1),1));
```

Full replacement:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_distance(character varying, 
double precision, double precision, 
double precision, double precision)

      RETURNS double precision AS
    $BODY$ 
            DECLARE earth_radius double precision; 

            BEGIN 
                    earth_radius := 3959.0; 

                    RETURN earth_radius *
acos(least(greatest(
    sin($2 / 57.2958) * 
    sin($4 / 57.2958) + cos($2/ 57.2958) * cos($4 / 57.2958) 
    * cos(($5 / 57.2958) - ($3 / 57.2958))
),-1),1));
            END; 
            $BODY$
      LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
      COST 100;
    ALTER FUNCTION calculate_distance(character varying, 
double precision, double precision, double precision, 
double precision) OWNER TO postgres;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I could not install the contrib modules (I was not the admin).

You can have a look here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

A numerically stable formula (for non antipodal points) is the following:

```
RETURN earth_radius * (2.*asin(sqrt((power(sin(radians(($4-$2)/2.)),2))+
(cos(radians($4))*cos(radians($2))*power(sin(radians(($5-$3)/2.)),2)))));
```

If you need an universal formula you can try to implement the one of the atan2 that is explained in the Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 0):

If coordinates the same you will get exception "[22003] ERROR: input is out of range". To prevent it just catch exception and return 0, like this:

```
EXCEPTION
WHEN numeric_value_out_of_range
THEN RETURN 0;
```