# Django sort by distance

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I have the following model:

```
class Vacancy(models.Model):
    lat = models.FloatField('Latitude', blank=True)
    lng = models.FloatField('Longitude', blank=True)
```

How should I make a query to sort by distance (distance is infinity)?

Working on PosgreSQL, GeoDjango if it is required.

Comment: What distance. Distance to what?

Comment: Without limit. Just sort from nearest to far.

Comment: @FallenAngel Update the Link to docs!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> Note: Please check cleder's answer below which mentions about
>   deprecation issue (distance -> annotation) in Django versions.

First of all, it is better to make a point field instead of making lat and lnt separated:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

location = models.PointField(null=False, blank=False, srid=4326, verbose_name='Location')
```

Then, you can filter it like that:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D

distance = 2000 
ref_location = Point(1.232433, 1.2323232)

res = YourModel.objects.filter(
    location__distance_lte=(
        ref_location,
        D(m=distance)
    )
).distance(
    ref_location
).order_by(
    'distance'
)
```

Comment: That's i want understand, why in this query filter, when i can't just: `res = mymodel.objects.order_by('location')`

Comment: If you want to make a sort on locations, there should be a reference location. You can sort the records around a specific place.

Comment: And in your query: D(m=distance), distance is it variable ?

Comment: a yes, i am adding it too, it is the most far place in meters.

Comment: you should also change the import in model too, i edited the example for that.

Comment: Is there any way of doing this without having to use PostGIS Fields like Point

Comment: @Sevenearthsü for that, you can make same trigonometry calculations with sin and cos, make a google search about it.

Comment: Please share the installation process of dependencies of geodjango

Comment: @RobertJohnstone Here is how to do it without POSTGIS https://stackoverflow.com/a/64746573/13789135

Answer (score 73):

the `.distance(ref_location)` is removed in django >=1.9 you should use an annotation instead.

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

ref_location = Point(1.232433, 1.2323232, srid=4326)
yourmodel.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(ref_location, D(m=2000)))                                                     
    .annotate(distance=Distance("location", ref_location))                                                                
    .order_by("distance")
```

also you should narrow down your search with the `dwithin` operator which uses the spatial index, distance does not use the index which slows your query down:

```
yourmodel.objects.filter(location__dwithin=(ref_location, 0.02))
    .filter(location__distance_lte=(ref_location, D(m=2000)))
    .annotate(distance=Distance('location', ref_location))
    .order_by('distance')
```

see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464666/distance-between-2-points-in-postgis-in-srid-4326-in-metres%20%22this%20post%22%20for%20an%20exlanation%20of) for an explanation of `location__dwithin=(ref_location, 0.02)`

Comment: Note: `D` is actually `django.contrib.gis.measure.Distance` which painfully shares the same name as the model function

Comment: I read this and the linked response, how do you define the `geom` variable?

Comment: If `geography=True` on the location (which it should be for a lat/lng), then `dwithin` is in meters on the surface of the sphere, not degrees. That means you don't need `distance_lte`.

Comment: correct if you use `geography` instead of `geometry` postgis can use an index for distance.

Comment: Use your code, I have ValueError: Cannot use object with type tuple for a spatial lookup parameter. In MySQL.

Comment: What if it is dynamic like user location, how do I compare user location, let's say shops within 2km?

Comment: Pass the current location to `ref_location`

Comment: @KaleabWoldemariam `ST_Within()` measures distance by stored EPSG units. As an example, I'm working with EPSG:3067 which has 1 meter accuracy, so I'm using `filter(location__dwithin=(ref_location, 200.0))` for querying "within 200 meters". You can use variable if necessary.

Answer (score 52):

Here is a solution that does not require GeoDjango.

```python
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL


class Location(models.Model):
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    ...


def get_locations_nearby_coords(latitude, longitude, max_distance=None):
    """
    Return objects sorted by distance to specified coordinates
    which distance is less than max_distance given in kilometers
    """
    # Great circle distance formula
    gcd_formula = "6371 * acos(least(greatest(\
    cos(radians(%s)) * cos(radians(latitude)) \
    * cos(radians(longitude) - radians(%s)) + \
    sin(radians(%s)) * sin(radians(latitude)) \
    , -1), 1))"
    distance_raw_sql = RawSQL(
        gcd_formula,
        (latitude, longitude, latitude)
    )
    qs = Location.objects.all() \
    .annotate(distance=distance_raw_sql) \
    .order_by('distance')
    if max_distance is not None:
        qs = qs.filter(distance__lt=max_distance)
    return qs
```

Use as follow:

```python
nearby_locations = get_locations_nearby_coords(48.8582, 2.2945, 5)
```

If you are using sqlite you need to add somewhere

```python
import math
from django.db.backends.signals import connection_created
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(connection_created)
def extend_sqlite(connection=None, **kwargs):
    if connection.vendor == "sqlite":
        # sqlite doesn't natively support math functions, so add them
        cf = connection.connection.create_function
        cf('acos', 1, math.acos)
        cf('cos', 1, math.cos)
        cf('radians', 1, math.radians)
        cf('sin', 1, math.sin)
        cf('least', 2, min)
        cf('greatest', 2, max)
```

Comment: How does the performance of this compare to the performance of doing it in PostGIS? I'm guessing it would be slower, but the computing would be done on the EC2 server rather than RDS, right? What if we only need a rough distance where an octagon or even a square would do, then using a custom manager would be significantly better than PostGIS I assume?

Comment: Really like this solution, no django GIS required, no libraries to be installed, just some math. I wonder if this works on any db? For me, it works perfectly on mysql. No performance issues so far, but only querying some 100 records.

Comment: only issue is that .extra() seems to be deprecated?!

Comment: @rphlo Is this distance in miles or kilometers?

Comment: The distance is in kilometers.

Comment: Having troubles with lat 50,8120466 lng 19,113213 with message: "ERROR:  input is out of range". Maybe this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533386/postgresql-error-error-input-is-out-of-range ?

Comment: Probably related Indeed, I can add `least(greatest(...),-1),1)` in the acos function

Comment: @Robert, were you able to sort out input out of range? I am getting a 'latitude doesn't exist' error could be related.

Comment: For SQLite3 where we have to add the code? You mentioned to add somewhere but in which page can you please tell?

Comment: You can add the sql specific code in your models.py file for example, since django will go through this file on startup

Answer (score 30):

*Best practice for this changes quite quickly, so I'll answer with what I think is most up-to-date as of 2020-01-18.*

## With GeoDjango

Using `geography=True` with GeoDjango makes this much easier. It means everything is stored in lng/lat, but distance calculations are done in meters on the surface of the sphere. [See the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#geography-type)

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import PointField

class Vacancy(models.Model):
    location = PointField(srid=4326, geography=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

### Django 3.0

If you have Django 3.0, you can sort your whole table using the following query. It uses postgis' `<->` operator, which means sorting will use the spacial index and the annotated distance will be exact (for Postgres 9.5+). Note that "sorting by distance" implicitly requires a distance *from* something. The first argument to `Point` is the longitude and the second is latitude (the opposite of the normal convention).

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import GeometryDistance
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

ref_location = Point(140.0, 40.0, srid=4326)
Vacancy.objects.order_by(GeometryDistance("location", ref_location))
```

If you want to use the distance from the reference point in any way, you'll need to annotate it:

```
Vacancy.objects.annotate(distance=GeometryDistance("location", ref_location))\
    .order_by("distance")
```

If you have a lot of results, calculating the exact distance for every entry will still be slow. You should reduce the number of results with one of the following:

#### Limit the number of results with queryset slicing

The `<->` operator won't calculate exact distance for (most) results it won't return, so slicing or paginating the results is fast. To get the first 100 results:

```
Vacancy.objects.annotate(distance=GeometryDistance("location", ref_location))\
    .order_by("distance")[:100]
```

#### Only get results within a certain distance with `dwithin`

If there is a maximum distance that you want results for, you should use `dwithin`. The `dwithin` django query uses ST_DWithin, which means it's very fast. **Setting geography=True means this calculation is done in meters, not degrees.** The final query for everything within 50km would be:

```
Vacancy.objects.filter(location__dwithin=(ref_location, 50000))\
    .annotate(distance=GeometryDistance("location", ref_location))\
    .order_by("distance")
```

This can speed up queries a bit even if you are slicing down to a few results.

The second argument to `dwithin` also accepts `django.contrib.gis.measure.D` objects, which it converts into meters, so instead of `50000` meters, you could just use `D(km=50)`.

#### Filtering on distance

You can filter directly on the annotated `distance`, but it will duplicate the `<->` call and be a fair amount slower than `dwithin`.

```
Vacancy.objects.annotate(distance=GeometryDistance("location", ref_location))\
    .filter(distance__lte=50000)\
    .order_by("distance")
```

### Django 2.X

If you don't have Django 3.0, you can still sort your whole table using `Distance` instead of `GeometryDistance`, but it uses ST_Distance, which might be slow if it is done on every entry and there are a lot of entries. If that's the case, you can use `dwithin` to narrow down the results.

Note that slicing will *not* be fast because `Distance` needs to calculate the exact distance for *everything* in order to sort the results.

## Without GeoDjango

If you don't have GeoDjango, you'll need a sql formula for calculating distance. The efficiency and correctness varies from answer to answer (especially around the poles/dateline), but in general it will be fairly slow.

One way to speed queries up is to index `lat` and `lng` and use mins/maxes for each before annotating the distance. The math is quite complicated because the bounding "box" isn't exactly a box. See here: [How to calculate the bounding box for a given lat/lng location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238260/how-to-calculate-the-bounding-box-for-a-given-lat-lng-location)

Answer (score 5):

On Django 3.0 there will be a [`GeometryDistance`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/functions/#django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions.GeometryDistance) function, which works the same way as `Distance`, but uses the [`<->` operator](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html) instead, which uses spatial indexes on `ORDER BY` queries, eliminating the need for a `dwithin` filter:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import GeometryDistance
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

ref_location = Point(140.0, 40.0, srid=4326)
Vacancy.objects.annotate(
    distance=GeometryDistance('location', ref_location)
).order_by('distance')
```

If you want to use it before Django 3.0 is released, you could use something like this:

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import GeoFunc
from django.db.models import FloatField
from django.db.models.expressions import Func

class GeometryDistance(GeoFunc):
   output_field = FloatField()
   arity = 2
   function = ''
   arg_joiner = ' <-> '
   geom_param_pos = (0, 1)

   def as_sql(self, *args, **kwargs):
       return Func.as_sql(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want/have no opportunity to use gis, here is sollution (haversine distance fomula writter in django orm sql):

```
lat = 52.100
lng = 21.021

earth_radius=Value(6371.0, output_field=FloatField())

f1=Func(F('latitude'), function='RADIANS')
latitude2=Value(lat, output_field=FloatField())
f2=Func(latitude2, function='RADIANS')

l1=Func(F('longitude'), function='RADIANS')
longitude2=Value(lng, output_field=FloatField())
l2=Func(longitude2, function='RADIANS')

d_lat=Func(F('latitude'), function='RADIANS') - f2
d_lng=Func(F('longitude'), function='RADIANS') - l2

sin_lat = Func(d_lat/2, function='SIN')
cos_lat1 = Func(f1, function='COS')
cos_lat2 = Func(f2, function='COS')
sin_lng = Func(d_lng/2, function='SIN')

a = Func(sin_lat, 2, function='POW') + cos_lat1 * cos_lat2 * Func(sin_lng, 2, function='POW')
c = 2 * Func(Func(a, function='SQRT'), Func(1 - a, function='SQRT'), function='ATAN2')
d = earth_radius * c

Shop.objects.annotate(d=d).filter(d__lte=10.0)
```

PS
change models, change filter to order_by, change keyword and parametrize

PS2
for sqlite3, you should ensure, that there are available function SIN, COS, RADIANS, ATAN2, SQRT

Answer (score 1):

**WITHOUT POSTGIS**

If you don't want to change your models i.e, keep lat and lng as seperate fields and even don't want to use too much Geodjango and want to solve this problem with some basic code then here is the solution;

```
origin = (some_latitude, some_longitude) #coordinates from where you want to measure distance
distance = {} #creating a dict which will store the distance of users.I am using usernames as keys and the distance as values.
for m in models.objects.all():
    dest = (m.latitude, m.longitude)
    distance[m.username] = round(geodesic(origin, dest).kilometers, 2) #here i am using geodesic function which takes two arguments, origin(coordinates from where the distance is to be calculated) and dest(to which distance is to be calculated) and round function rounds off the float to two decimal places

#Here i sort the distance dict as per value.So minimum distant users will be first.
s_d = sorted(distance.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]) #note that sorted function returns a list of tuples as a result not a dict.Those tuples have keys as their first elements and vaues as 2nd.

new_model_list = []
for i in range(len(s_d)):
    new_model_list.append(models.objects.get(username=s_d[i][0]))
```

Now the new_model_list will contain all the users ordered in distance.By iterating over it, you will get them ordered on the basis of distance.

**WITH POSTGIS**

Add a point field in your models;

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class your_model(models.Model):
    coords = models.PointField(null=False, blank=False, srid=4326, verbose_name='coords')
```

Then in views.py;

```
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions import Distance
from .models import your_model

user = your_model.objects.get(id=some_id) # getting a user with desired id

sortedQueryset = your_model.objects.all().annotate(distance=Distance('coords', user.coords, spheroid=True)).order_by('distance')
```

`Distance` function takes first parameter as the field from the database against which we have to calculate the distance (here coords).
2nd parameter is the coordinates from which the distance is to be calculated.

`Spheroid` specifies the accuracy of the distance. By setting this to `True`, it will give more accurate distance else less accurate as for `Spheroid = False`, it treats points as the points on a sphere (which is wrong for earth).

Answer (score 0):

in views.py use CustomHaystackGEOSpatialFilter for filter_backends :

```
class LocationGeoSearchViewSet(HaystackViewSet):
    index_models = [yourModel]
    serializer_class = LocationSerializer
    filter_backends = [CustomHaystackGEOSpatialFilter]
```

in filters.py define CustomHaystackGEOSpatialFilter and override apply_filters method so you can order the distance and limit your result count like :

```
class CustomHaystackGEOSpatialFilter(HaystackGEOSpatialFilter):
    # point_field = 'location'
   def apply_filters(self, queryset, applicable_filters=None, applicable_exclusions=None):
        if applicable_filters:
            queryset = queryset.dwithin(**applicable_filters["dwithin"]).distance(
                **applicable_filters["distance"]).order_by("distance")[:100]
        return queryset
```