# How to implement sorting with custom function in DjangoREST?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am currently using DjangoREST for a server.
When I want to do is to sort a queryset according to a custom function.

For an illustration a model could be like this:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    latitude = models.FloatField()
    longitude = models.FloatField()
```

In detail, I would like to send a request with my current geological coordinates and I would like the response to be sorted according to the distance between the product and myself.

I am using `ModelSerializers` and `mixins` if that is relevant.

The calculation is non-trivial which means it could not be accomplished by SQL sentences so `annotate` is not very useful in this case. And if I use:

```
queryset = Product.objects.all()
result = sort(queryset,lambda a: Somefunction(a))
```

The `result` is a list which is no longer a queryset, so I could not override the `filter_queryset` or relevant methods of DjangoREST `filter` class as they expect a queryset to be returned.

How could I accomplish this seemingly simple task with DjangoREST?

Comment: Why not convert the list to json and send that as the response?

Comment: Are you using `GeoDjango`? Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703975/django-sort-by-distance

Comment: @themanatuf Thank you very much for the link!

Comment: Sorting by what ? If you want to sort by any custom function then what is the index actually depending on you want to sort ?